# Oracle9i-why this left join return empty result?

Tags: sql, oracle

> A LEFT OUTER JOIN is one of the JOIN operations that allow you to
>   specify a join clause. It preserves the unmatched rows from the first
>   (left) table, joining them with a NULL row in the shape of the second
>   (right) table.

Why the result of the last two queries is empty？

```
SELECT *
FROM PTB_YSQK;
-- 10 rows

SELECT *
FROM PTB_FP;
-- 10 rows

SELECT *
FROM PTB_YSQK
  LEFT JOIN PTB_FP ON PTB_FP.YSID = PTB_YSQK.ID;
-- 10 rows

SELECT *
FROM PTB_YSQK
  LEFT JOIN PTB_FP ON PTB_FP.ID IS NULL;
-- 0 rows

SELECT *
FROM PTB_YSQK
  LEFT JOIN PTB_FP ON PTB_FP.ID = (
    SELECT min(PTB_FP.ID)
    FROM PTB_FP
    WHERE PTB_FP.YSID = PTB_YSQK.ID
  )
-- 0 rows
```

For detail of those tables, see https://gist.github.com/toaco/f3821f69ad86889abb43878ac2b4978d

Comment: Have 10 rows per table. Do `select *` instead of `select count(*)`.

Comment: Use WHERE instead of ON - WHERE PTB_FP.ID IS NULL

Comment: @Thilo That doesn't explain why 0 rows get returned. It's a left join.

Comment: @AswaniMadhavan You changed it into a syntax error. That doesn't really help.

Comment: Can you provide a small dataset to reproduce this?

Comment: @HVD You need to have a ON clause on the  common fields and need to add the condition PTB_FP.ID IS NULL in WHERE clause.Something like SELECT * FROM PTB_YSQK LEFT JOIN PTB_FP ON PTB_FP.YSID = PTB_YSQK.ID WHERE PTB_FP.ID IS NULL